# XML IF-THEN-ELSE

Tags: xml, if-statement

I have this piece of a program that I have attempted to transform to get a different output per register. If it is register #5 then I want it to print the THEN TEXT, if it is not #5 then print ELSE TEXT. It is halfway working but it seems that when I print an "X-Report" from register 1 it shows 'Store A XStore A ZStore A ZZ...' and if I print from register 5 it shows 
'X ReportZ ReportZZ Report...' 
I would think once it hits the end of the IF statement then it would stop looking to print more info. Here is a copy of my code:

```
<TABLE>
  <FONT> "Large" </FONT>
  <BORDER> tball </BORDER>
  <COLUMNHEADER>
       <ALIGNMENT> "^~" </ALIGNMENT>
       <WIDTH> PageWidth </WIDTH>
       <IF>
           <CONDITION> (Register.Number = 5 &amp; Transaction.Type = transactionXReport) </CONDITION>
           <THEN> 
               <TEXT> "X REPORT" </TEXT>
           </THEN>
           <ELSE>
               <TEXT> "STORE A X" </TEXT>
           </ELSE>
       </IF>
       <IF>
           <CONDITION> (Register.Number = 5 &amp; Transaction.Type = transactionZReport) </CONDITION>
           <THEN> 
               <TEXT> "Z REPORT" </TEXT>
           </THEN>
           <ELSE>
               <TEXT> "STORE A Z" </TEXT>
           </ELSE>
       </IF>
       <IF>
           <CONDITION> (Register.Number = 5 &amp; Transaction.Type = transactionZZReport) </CONDITION>
           <THEN> 
               <TEXT> "ZZ REPORT" </TEXT>
           </THEN>
           <ELSE>
               <TEXT> "STORE A ZZ" </TEXT>
           </ELSE>
       </IF>
       <IF>
           <CONDITION> (Register.Number = 5 &amp; Transaction.Type = transactionXReport) </CONDITION>
           <THEN> 
               <TEXT> "BLIND REPORT" </TEXT>
           </THEN>
           <ELSE>
               <TEXT> "STORE A BLIND" </TEXT>
           </ELSE>
       </IF>
   </COLUMNHEADER>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: XML is barely more executable than a `.txt` file. What's important is what program interprets the XML.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is written in some XML-based programming language, but I don't recognize the programming language and you haven't told us anything about it. So how can we help you debug your program, if we know nothing about the language it is written in?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is Microsoft Dynamics RMS Register XML code.  I'd suggest debugging this by printing out the value of Transaction.Type, it must be matching all of the listed transaction types.